# JOB Actualizar un campo en base a otro campo DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

Estoy realizando un job en sql server.

Creo una tabla temporal donde coloco los datos de mi tabla original. Aqui todo OK

Seguido cuento los datos que tiene mi tabla temporal y realizo un while para recorrer mi tabla temporal para obtener cantidad de filas que tiene. Aqui todo OK

Seguido de esto realizo un select a la tabla temporal y obtengo la fecha para compararla con la fecha del servidor usando GETDATE() dentro de un IF.

Aqui mi query apartir del While:

```
 DECLARE @count INT;
 DECLARE @fch2  DATETIME;
 SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM #Suple;/*cuento filas de tabla temporal*/
 WHILE @count > 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT  @fch2 = FCH_FIN FROM #Suple WHERE ACTIVO = 1 and Convert(Date,FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE());/*obtengo las fechas del dia*/
 IF (GETDATE() = @fch2)/*comparo las fechas*/
 UPDATE TableOriginal SET ACTIVO = 0/*actulizo mi tabla original si es igua*/
 DELETE TOP(1) FROM #Suple /*borro la primer fila recorrida de temporal*/
 SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Suple);/*vuelvo a contar las filas de temporal*/

 END
 DROP TABLE #Suple/*al finalizar borro temporal*/
```

Estos son los campos de mi tabla Original y tal cual se pasan a #Suple que es la tabla temporal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El job esta programado para que se ejecute cada hora(7:00 AM - 19:00 PM) de lunes a viernes pero no me actualiza el campo que quiero a la hora que se ejecuta.

Este ejemplo lo puse a las 11:15 AM, agrego los dos registros de Original a Temporal y debio actualizar una fila pero paso el tiempo y no actualizo mi campo :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden apoyar a resolverlo...

**EDITADO** definicion del Job

```
USE [msdb]
GO

 /****** Object:  Job [Suplentes]    Script Date: 11/08/2019 13:32:54 ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]]    Script Date: 
11/08/2019 13:32:54 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE 
name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', 
@name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Suplentes', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
    @notify_level_email=0, 
    @notify_level_netsend=0, 
    @notify_level_page=0, 
    @delete_level=0, 
    @description=N'Habilitar y deshabilitar los suplentes.', 
    @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
    @owner_login_name=N'NA\user', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [VerificaTiempos]    Script Date: 11/08/2019 13:32:54 
******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, 
@step_name=N'VerificaTiempos', 
    @step_id=1, 
    @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
    @on_success_action=1, 
    @on_success_step_id=0, 
    @on_fail_action=2, 
    @on_fail_step_id=0, 
    @retry_attempts=0, 
    @retry_interval=0, 
    @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
    @command=N'DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @fch2  DATETIME;
CREATE table #Suple(
ACTIVO NCHAR(10) not null,
FCH_INICIO DATETIME not null,
FCH_FIN DATETIME not null
);
INSERT INTO #Suple SELECT * FROM  Original where ACTIVO = 1 and 
Convert(Date,FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE());

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM #Suple;
WHILE @count > 0
BEGIN
SELECT  @fch2 = FCH_FIN FROM #Suple WHERE ACTIVO = 1 and Convert(Date,FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE());
IF (GETDATE() = @fch2)
UPDATE Original SET ACTIVO = 0
DELETE TOP(1) FROM #Suple
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Suple);

END
DROP TABLE #Suple', 
    @database_name=N'database', 
    @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, 
@name=N'JobSche1', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @freq_type=8, 
    @freq_interval=62, 
    @freq_subday_type=1, 
    @freq_subday_interval=1, 
    @freq_relative_interval=0, 
    @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
    @active_start_date=20191105, 
    @active_end_date=99991231, 
    @active_start_time=111500, 
    @active_end_time=235959, 
    @schedule_uid=N'ae0af8c4-c8dd-4027-964c-601e684481aa'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name 
= N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

Comment: ¿Existe alguna razón para no actualizar todas las filas en una sola instrucción en vez de usar un código más lento que un cursor? ¿Puedes poner toda la definición del job (Script Job as...), así como el detalle del Job Activity Monitor?

Comment: R1: si hay otra forma de hacerlo, se aceptan sugerencias, siempre y cuando el resultado sea el mismo. R2: edite la pregunta y puse el Scrip

Comment: Faltó poner el historial de ejecuciones. Al menos el resultado de esta consulta. `SELECT last_run_date, last_run_time, last_run_outcome, last_run_retries 
FROM dbo.sysjobsteps
WHERE step_name = 'VerificaTiempos'`

Answer (score 1):

La definición del job es correcta (teniendo en cuenta que se ocultó el nombre de login, de la base de datos y la tabla). El código se puede simplificar con un simple UPDATE que hace lo que necesitas, no se requiere ir fila por fila.

```
    /*actualizo mi tabla original si es igual*/
    UPDATE T
    SET ACTIVO = 0
    FROM TABLEORIGINAL T
    WHERE ACTIVO = 1 
    AND CONVERT(DATE,FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

Usando el siguiente código, pude hacer que el job hiciera lo necesario sin problema.

```
USE [msdb]
GO

 /****** Object:  Job [Suplentes]    Script Date: 11/08/2019 13:32:54 ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]]    Script Date: 
11/08/2019 13:32:54 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE 
name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', 
@name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Suplentes', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
    @notify_level_email=0, 
    @notify_level_netsend=0, 
    @notify_level_page=0, 
    @delete_level=0, 
    @description=N'Habilitar y deshabilitar los suplentes.', 
    @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
    @owner_login_name=N'NA\user', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [VerificaTiempos]    Script Date: 11/08/2019 13:32:54 
******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, 
@step_name=N'VerificaTiempos', 
    @step_id=1, 
    @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
    @on_success_action=1, 
    @on_success_step_id=0, 
    @on_fail_action=2, 
    @on_fail_step_id=0, 
    @retry_attempts=0, 
    @retry_interval=0, 
    @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
    @command=N'
    UPDATE T
    SET ACTIVO = 0
    FROM TABLEORIGINAL T
    WHERE ACTIVO = 1 
    AND CONVERT(DATE,FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())/*actulizo mi tabla original si es igua*/', 
    @database_name=N'Database', 
    @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

DECLARE @schedule_uid uniqueidentifier;

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, 
@name=N'JobSche1', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @freq_type=8, 
    @freq_interval=62, 
    @freq_subday_type=1, 
    @freq_subday_interval=1, 
    @freq_relative_interval=0, 
    @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
    @active_start_date=20191105, 
    @active_end_date=99991231, 
    @active_start_time=154500, 
    @active_end_time=235959, 
    @schedule_uid=@schedule_uid
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name 
= N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

Comment: estoy intentando pero no me actualiza a la hora exacta a como estan los registros, por ejemplo aqui CONVERT(DATE,FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) solo esta actulizando con la fecha pero no toma en cuenta la hora, yo tengo registrado en mi tabla 2019-11-11 07:00:00.000 y quiero comparar ese campo con GETDATE() pero nunca sucede porque quizas en la comparacion el getdate ya pasaron unos segundos y nunca es igual a mi registro.

Comment: Desde tu código original se toma en cuenta solo la fecha para la comparación. El código toma todas las filas con la misma fecha sin importar la hora.

Comment: es correcto... pero quisiera tomar en cuenta la hora pero cuando ejecuto getdate nunca coincide imagino por cuestion de segundos.